# How to create new command that will produce list of items while changing formatting of single item

Tags: macros, lists, itemize

I have a list of items with list of topics which is put at the beggining of each chapter. There is 1-1 relationship between topics and chapters. The list should be modified for each chapter, so for example in the second chapter it will look like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item topic A
\item \tetxfbf{topic B}
\item topic C
\end{itemize}
```

I'd like to avoid having the same set of items in each chapter, the only difference being the highlighted item. 
Is there a way how to create `\newcommand` that will take an argument saying which topic to highlight ?

Answer (score 3):

It's indeed best to define a command in the preamble, where you can edit in all topics

```
\newcommand{\topics}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \topic{1}{topic A}
  \topic{2}{topic B}
  \topic{3}{topic C}
  \topic{4}{topic D}
  \end{itemize}%
}
\newcommand{\topic}[2]{%
  \item\relax
  \ifnum #1=\value{chapter}%
    \textbf{#2}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}
```

Then you will simply type

```
\chapter{Title}
\topics
```